# How do I track the parent data item of a nested ListView?

Tags: asp.net, listview, parent-child

I have an asp:ListView control with a data pager control in it.  In the ItemTemplate of this list view, I have a child asp:ListView control, also with a data pager control in it.  When I click the next page (or any page) of the data pager in the child list view, paging doesn't move.

I solved this problem by subscribing to the PagePropertiesChanged event of the child list view and rebinding ONLY the child data list for the child list view control that fired the event.  I managed to test this only because I knew which parent object I was working on.  My question is: what strategies has anyone used to figure out after a postback what parent object "owns" a child ListView that is triggering an event?